# Expected function body after function declarator c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to override virtual funtions to create an account hierarchy, but I'm getting an error when I try to override the `withdraw` function:

```
bool Checking_Account::withdraw (double amount) override {
    amount += per_check_fee;
    return Account::withdraw(amount);
}
```

[image]

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: `override` is only valid on a function definition when used inline in the class definition. If you defined the class and you are now defining this function _outside_ the class, you must omit the `override` specifier.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). As-is, we can't see the actual error message.

Comment: You seems to only have provided the definition (outside the derived class) but not the declaration inside the class. However, there is too little information to really know as you didn't provide the declaration of the class or the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you currently have this scenario:

```
class Account {
public:
    virtual ~Account() {}
    virtual bool withdraw (double amount);
};

class Checking_Account : public Account
{
public:
    bool withdraw (double amount) override;
    // ...
};
```

The `override` specifier is only relevant when declaring overridden methods inside the class definition. When it comes to defining your function externally to the class, it must be omitted. Note below that `override` is *not* used for the method definition:

```
class Checking_Account : public Account
{
public:
    bool withdraw (double amount) override;
    // ...
};

bool Checking_Account::withdraw (double amount)
{
    amount += per_check_fee;
    return Account::withdraw(amount);
}
```

This type of error commonly occurs when you are refactoring code that previously had inline method definitions. For instance, perhaps you previously had the following, which is also fine:

```
class Checking_Account : public Account
{
public:
    bool withdraw (double amount) override
    {
        amount += per_check_fee;
        return Account::withdraw(amount);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: thx so much that clearly helps me solve the problem！

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, which apparently it did, the recommendation is to show your appreciation as detailed here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)